# SQL - Max distance between series of points

Tags: sql, max, distance

Sorry if i have missed it elsewhere, is there a way to find the largest distance between a list of points (x,y)?

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGHfC.png)

Comment: How much data do you have?  You could cross-join, but that would be very inefficient in a large dataset.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cross-join to get all combinations of points, then use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distances.  This is likely inefficient for a large dataset, though.

```
Select *, sqrt(power(a.x-b.x, 2) + power(a.y-b.y, 2)) as Distance
from MyData a
Join MyData b
on a.locationcode > b.locationcode --so you don't get all combination of points a,b and b,a returned
```

You could also write it as `MyData a cross join MyData b` and then filter out rows that joined to themselves (or ignore them, since the distance will be 0 in those cases).

To get just the largest, something like this:

```
Select top 1 *, sqrt(power(a.x-b.x, 2) + power(a.y-b.y, 2)) as Distance
from MyData a
Join MyData b
on a.locationcode > b.locationcode
order by Distance desc
```

(Note, you may need something more complex if you want to see all sets of points in the event that there are ties).

Comment: Legend, only issue was that SQL wasnt accepting the ^ operator. just modified it to 
`Select top 1 *, sqrt(power((a.[PointX]-b.[PointX]),2) + power((a.[PointY]-b.[PointY]),2)) as Distance
from dbo.GetPoints() a
Join dbo.GetPoints() b
on a.locationcode > b.locationcode
order by Distance desc` and it worked 
perfectly. much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated to use `power` - sorry, was mixing up syntax with statistical software.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by APH is perfectly valid, but as stated may run into problems with large datasets. For the benefit of future readers, I'll post an alternative which should be efficient with large datasets:

1. Find the centroid of the set of points
2. Find the furthest vertex from the centroid
3. Find the longest edge between the furthest vertex and any other vertex

Here is the solution for SQL Server:

```
-- Find the centroid of the set of points
DECLARE @centroid_x DECIMAL(18,6);
DECLARE @centroid_y DECIMAL(18,6);
SET @centroid_x = (SELECT AVG(x) FROM points);
SET @centroid_y = (SELECT AVG(y) FROM points);

-- Find the furthest vertex from the centroid
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #furthest_point;
SELECT
    x, y
INTO #furthest_point
FROM (
    SELECT
        points.x,
        points.y,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SQRT((points.x - @centroid_x)^2 + (points.y - @centroid_y)^2) DESC) AS rn
    FROM points
) fp
WHERE fp.rn = 1;

-- Find the longest edge between the furthest vertex and any other vertex
SELECT
    MAX(
        SQRT(
            POWER(fp.x - p.x, 2) + POWER(fp.y - p.y, 2)
        )
    ) AS maximum_distance
FROM points p
CROSS JOIN furthest_point fp;
```